# PHP GET and POST request in signle page what is happning

Tags: php

I have  PHP code that do the following things
1-get some request parameters from parent page
2-send post request for it self and validate data
3-redirect the combined data to the next page

here is sample snippet

I am having difficult time fixing my messy code... pleas help me!

```
<?php

//on page load---from parent page
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

 $room_number=$_GET['room_number'];
 } 


 //on submit
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    //do some stuff... validation
   if($valid){
       // if valide redirect to ...
       header("Location: RegisterUser.php?name=".$name."&lastname=".$lastname."&     roomnumber=".$room_number."");
    exit();

           }
        }

     ?>
   <form action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' method='post' >
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="text" name="lastname">

    </form>
```

the problem i am having is at the redirection $room_number is empty always
how can i fix it??
I know i am doing a lot of stuff in single file that is because i am very beginner.

it would be great if someone can suggest me better way to so such stuff.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: There are 2 issues primarily. `if($valid)` will always be same because you are not initializing it anywhere. Secondly when your request method is post you are not initializing the variable named `$room_number`

Comment: This means that the GET request from the parent page is not sending any data? Where is the parent page, i mean is it your file only from which room number is coming?

Comment: @MixedVeg No there is other file sending GET request to this page!

Comment: and that is sending you the room number? If i am understanding it right!

Comment: @MixedVeg you right!

Comment: Follow the answer by @Manish, this will do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use hidden input for room_number input.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $room_number = $_POST['room_number'];
    header("Location: RegisterUser.php?name=".$name."&lastname=".$lastname."&roomnumber=".$room_number);
    exit();
}
?>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="name"> 
    <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="room_number" value="<?php echo $room_number; ?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then use the above code in your file. It may help you. And Why are you redirecting those variables to another register page. Just use them in itself to insert into database or anything else what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add your $room_number in your form as a hidden input field so that you can pass it through as a post variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="room_number" value="<?php echo $room_number; ?>" />
```